Finding norms on $\mathbb{R}[X]$
Considering for all $n$ in $\mathbb{N}$,  $P_n = X^n$, propose norms $N_1, N_2, N_3$ on $\mathbb{R}[X]$ such that:
$N_1(P_n)$ tends towards $0$ as $n$ approaches $+\infty$ ;
$N_2(P_n) = 1$ ;
$N_3(P_n)$ tends to $+\infty$ as $n$ approaches $+\infty$
Please, help me find these norms. Thank you for your help and your time.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Hint: Think of polynomials as functions $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ (real sequences), and think of norms you already know in this context.
Solution:

 We can take 3 different weighted versions of the $\ell^1$ norm:

 
 $N_1(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n X^n) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n +1}|a_n|$ ;
 $N_2(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n X^n) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n|$; 
 $N_3(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n X^n) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n +1)|a_n|$. 

 Verify for yourself that these are indeed norms, and that they satisfy the properties that you need.

